# Twilio TaskRouter JS SDK not working

Tags: vue.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

According to Twilio Docs I'm trying develop a Call-center Application But The TaskRouter JS

> v1.13/taskrouter.min.js
>   Not supporting as twilio explain in document https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/worker#reservation-created

```
worker.on("reservation.created", function(reservation) {
    console.log(reservation.task.attributes)      // NOT FOUND
    console.log(reservation.task.priority)        // NOT FOUND
    console.log(reservation.task.age)             // NOT FOUND
    console.log(reservation.task.sid)             // NOT FOUND
    console.log(reservation.sid)                  // RETURNS task sid
});
```

**reservation.sid** print **task sid** & If I remove **.task** It returns respective output related to task But here I expect reservation related output.

Below are twilio client SDK are currently used in my application.

1. https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/sync/releases/0.5.10/twilio-sync.js
2. https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/releases/1.4.31/twilio.min.js
3. https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.13/taskrouter.min.js
4. https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js

Comment: The code you've shared is exactly as it appears in your application?

Comment: @thanksd yes, this event trigger at the time taskrouter create reservation but reservation.task.attributes, ...  values are not found & reservation.sid providing task.sid value!!!.

Comment: This is very unusual that how a cloud messaging provider don't support it's won technical documentation & also I'm going to create the technical support ticket - Twilio.

Comment: Can you share the link for your support ticket?

Comment: @thanksd According to Twilio ticket response

"As per discussion with engineering, the issue is that you are including https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js in your application. 

If you remove that, everything is expected to work as documented.

It looks to be an old version of the SDK, and it initially returned a task object instead of a reservation for the method mentioned. 

Because both the old and the current are included, the old is overwriting some of the functions used by the current SDK."

Comment: v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js   Javascript SDK providing worker events to the registered on Worker object   https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js

Comment: If I remove '.. v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js  ' these above worker https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/worker#worker-events event functionality stopped working. @thanksd Ticket stile on progress, They have some issue with latest v1.13 SDK & Twilio ticket response on own mistake is very very slow.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the "event functionality stopped working"? The callback wasn't firing?

Comment: @thanksd Yes, After remove '.. v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js ' ,worker stop receiving event callback in existence implementation.

"worker.on("activity.update", function (worker) {
...//
}"
Callback stopped firing.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this yet? If not, I'd love to try to help get you over the line. I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio.

Comment: yes, thanks @philnash

Comment: Cool! Thanks for letting me know and glad you could move on with your app!

Comment: @SamDev please post how you managed to solve this.

Comment: Sure @joshuamabina

Comment: @philnash , As you know Issues never stop Development. In this situation, we just need use our brain little more 0.%, Otherwise It's kills your times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was two different issue but It related to each other.

> First I remove
>
> > 4. https://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js
> >
> > It fixed
>
> ```
> worker.on("reservation.created", function(reservation) {
>          console.log(reservation.task.attributes)      // FOUND
>          console.log(reservation.task.priority)        // FOUND
>          console.log(reservation.task.age)             // FOUND
>          console.log(reservation.task.sid)             // FOUND
>          console.log(reservation.sid)                  // RETURNS reservation sid 
> });
> ```

**`BUT After I remove  taskrouter.worker.min.js , I faced another issue (i.e worker event stopped working)`**

> ```
> worker.on("ready", function(worker) {
> });
> ```
>
> Because both version use different key to get event value
>
> 1. /v1.13/taskrouter.min.js for  example **worker.activityName**
> 2. /v1.0/taskrouter.worker.min.js for example  **worker.activity_name**
>
> Secondly , I need to update all key according to 
>   /v1.13/taskrouter.min.js in my client side Js
>   For example, Replace ***worker.activity_name*** with updated key ***worker.activityName*** according to
>   **v1.13**

This resolve all of my issue.